# One to many table joined to summary table

Tags: sql-server, join

I need to join following two tables:

```
Transactions (multiple rows per person)
LedgerSummary (Summary table) - one row per person
```

How do I join these two tables, but not get LedgerSummary data attached to each row of Transactions?  I only want LedgerSummary data attached to first row of transaction per person (ID).

Both of these tables have PersonID column I can join on.  However, LedgerSummary has an Amount field.  The SUM(Amount) would be wrong if I do a regular left or right join because how these two tables are related.  That is the reason I want Amount to only appear once for each person instead of every single row.

Comment: Can you please add what columns you have for each table.

Comment: Done.  It is the SUM(Amount) issue.  I don't want the amount of multiply because Transactions table has more than one row per person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;With cteTransactions As
(
Select *, Row_Number() Over (Partition By IdThatLinksToTransAndLedger, Order By
    ColumnToGivePriorityOnSelectingOneTransaction) SortOrder
   From Transactions
)  
Select *
   From LedgerSummary L
   Join (Select * From cteTransactions Where SortOrder = 1) T 
      On L.IdThatLinksToTransAndLedger = T.IdThatLinksToTransAndLedger
```

IdThatLinksToTransAndLedger - You need a key for Person
ColumnToGivePriorityOnSelectingOneTransaction - Priority column, usually a date descending to give most recent.